# Add typing for function component in React JS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I noticed that some of developers type react js functional component like this:

```
const Result: React.FC<ResultProps> = ({ prop1, prop2 }: ResultProps) => {
```

I don't understand the idea, why they use `ResultProps` 2 times. Is not enough to type the component in this way:

```
const Result: React.FC<ResultProps> = ({ prop1, prop2 }) => {
```

?

What is the difference between these 2 ways of typing? I tried both implementation and got the same result.

Comment: Feel free to omit `ResultProps`. It should not affect type of argument since it is already declared here `React.FC<ResultProps>`

Comment: There is absolutely no point in writing down the type annotation aside the props as it is typed already with the `FC` generic type. So the devs you saw write components like this might reconsider their understanding of TS

Comment: Side note: It's "function component," not "functional component." Function components are often not [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is not enough to type the component in this way:

Yes, that's enough. You don't have to repeat the type of the props, this is just fine:

```typescript
const Result: React.FC<ResultProps> = ({ prop1, prop2 }) => {
    // ...
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3SUSQGcBXAGxgAUcxWcAN7k4YuGH4BGAFxxWMKDQDmFcRP4AmOQqXVV5AL6U0EagpYduc5OhgA6AGIBhADzIrvfqwB8cALxwABRCGhBgUgA0YWCacIYAlAF+IupEMOxQ1HCuACbAAG5wAPQ+FIakQA)

That works because you've already set the type of `Result`, so TypeScript knows what parameters the function accepts and their types.

---

A note about `React.FC`: In the types for React v17.x and below, when you used `React.FC` for your component, you were saying it supported children. Your component doesn't support children, so I thought I should call it out. Many people started saying not to use `React.FC` for this very reason: it was easy to accidentally give your component the wrong type information. But in React v18.x and above, they changed the definition of `React.FC` so that it no longer assumes your component supports children. (If you want to say it does, you add `PropsWithChildren` like this: `React.FC<PropsWithChildren<ResultProps>>`.)

So if you're using v17.x or below and you don't want the component to say it supports children when it doesn't, here's an alternative way to do the types for it that you often see:

```typescript
const Result = ({ prop1, prop2 }: ResultProps) => {
    // ...
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3SUSQGcBXAGxgAUcxWcAN7k4YuGH4BGAFxxWMKDQDmFcRP4AmOQqXVV5AL6U0EagpYducALxwAFEI0QwUgDTOwmuIbnIrvPysAJS2AHzCouJEMOxQ1HAAPAAmwABucAD0YRSGpEA)

Note, though, that that relies on you returning the correct thing from the component, since there's no return type annotation TypeScript can use to help you if you forget to return something or return something that isn't valid for a component (like returning a plain object). So you might include a return type as well:

```typescript
const Result = ({ prop1, prop2 }: ResultProps): JSX.Element => {
    // ...
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3SUSQGcBXAGxgAUcxWcAN7k4YuGH4BGAFxxWMKDQDmFcRP4AmOQqXVV5AL6U0EagpYducALxwAFEI0QwUgDTOwmuIbnIrvPysAJRyAFIAygAaAHQAopxIIEi0tgB8wqLiRDDsUNRwADwAJsAAbnAA9GkUhqRAA)

But again, in the types for React v18.x, `React.FC` no longer assumes your component supports children.

Comment: `Beware that using React.FC in slightly older versions of React ` - What do you mean? Should i use another way of typing?

Comment: @Asking - In the types for React v17.x and below, when you used `React.FC`, it meant that your component was saying it supported having children. But many components don't, and people didn't realize their component types were saying they did, so some folks said that using `React.FC` was poor practice. In React v18.x and above, they updated the types so that `React.FC` no longer assumes your component supports children; instead, if it should, you can use `PropsWithChildren` to say that: `React.FC<PropsWithChildren<ResultProps>>`).